# Activating conda environment from bash script

Tags: bash, conda, sshpass

I would like to change my conda environment from a bash script.
I want to run `bash script_yxz`, where 'script_xyz' is like:

```
#!/bin/bash

conda activate my_env
```

and switch to my_env.

This already works if I run `source script_yxz`.
But I have the problem that I am not able to 'source' on remote machines with 'sshpass'.

To better understand my purposes, my goal is to run on my terminal

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -o user@server "bash script_xyz"
```

and changing the environment on the server.
This is why I need to use bash instead of source.

I have read a lot of solutions on various forums but none of them works.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1442641/activating-conda-environment-over-ssh

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash

eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh

conda create -n testing python=3.10 -y

conda activate testing
python --version
```

#output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

seems like the conda script is not imported by default so this should fix it

```
source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate <env>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `bash`,`zsh` or any shell **aliases** for this purposes. You just add

```
alias my_conda='source /home/$USER/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate MyPy38'
```

line into the `.bashrc`,`.zshrc` or `.any_other_shell_rc`.

**"N.B. My environment name is `MyPy38`"**. So,replace it according name as well as the path `/home/$USER/anaconda3`.
Also you can create separate file for aliases. Just create a file called `.bash_aliases` and add

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

lines to `.bashrc`,`.zshrc` or `.any_other_shell_rc` and keep the command

```
alias my_conda='source /home/$USER/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate MyPy38'
```

into the `.bash_aliases`. Now,  `source ~/.zshrc ~/.bashrc` or just close and open a new terminal. Run the command `my_conda` and **BOOM!**

Also, you can add some other aliases for `jupyter-notebook` `jupyter-lab` `spyder` etc. like

```
# Just activate my conda
alias my_conda='source /home/$USER/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate MyPy38'

# Open Jupyter Notebook in my Env
alias my_jupn='source /home/$USER/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate MyPy38 && jupyter-notebook'

# Open Jupyter Lab in my Env
alias my_jupl='source /home/$USER/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate MyPy38 && jupyter-lab'

# Open Spyder in my Env
alias my_spyder='source /home/$USER/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate MyPy38 && spyder'
```

To confirm active environment name python code

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```