# How to set default folder in JupyterLab file browser?

Tags: directory, configuration, default, jupyter-lab, file-browser

I was wondering if there is a way to set a default folder every time I open JupyterLab. Is there any command I can run through Anaconda PowerShell Prompt? Or a JSON property I can modify in settings tab? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40514875/6646912 could help you, but use `jupyter server --generate-config` instead, and `c.ServerApp.root_dir`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to open specific file in directory `a`, say `a/notebook.ipynb` but then navigate the file browser to directory `b`, **relative to the root directory**, you can use `file-browser-path` query in the navigation URL ([documented here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/urls.html#file-navigation-with-tree)):

```
http(s)://<server:port>/<lab-location>/lab/tree/a/notebook.ipynb?file-browser-path=/b
```

You can use this method from command line thanks to `LabApp.default_url` traitlet:

```
jupyter-lab --LabApp.default_url='/lab/tree/a/notebook.ipynb?file-browser-path=/b'
```

You can skip the opening specific file part:

```
jupyter-lab --LabApp.default_url='/lab?file-browser-path=/b'
```

If you want to **change the root directory**, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40514875/6646912) which explains how to do so with `ServerApp.root_dir` traitlet (in older versions of Notebook<7.0 and JupyterLab<3.0 used to be named `NotebookApp.notebook_dir`). Again, you can use it from command line, and even specify an absolute path:

```
jupyter-lab --ServerApp.root_dir='/home/user/project/'
# or on Windows say:
# jupyter-lab --ServerApp.root_dir='C/users/user/project/'
```

You can combine the two approaches, e.g.:

```
jupyter-lab --ServerApp.root_dir='/home/user/project/' --LabApp.default_url='/lab?file-browser-path=/project_subdirectory'
```

If you want to persist the changes (for either default URL or root dir), see the previously [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40514875/6646912) which details how to persist configuration.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jupyter.org](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/change-default-working-directory-in-jupyterlab-on-linux/11066/3):
I configured like this.

Terminal command active your envirnment by `conda activate Your_env_name` and then `jupyter lab --generate-config`. **jupyter_lab_config.py** should be created in dir **/home/$USER/.jupyter** directory.

Find
`# c.LabApp.app_settings_dir = ''` and uncomment.

Then give your directory like this.
`c.LabApp.app_settings_dir = '/home/$USER/Documents/Jupyter_Notebook'`

Similar for jupyter notebook. `jupyter notebook --generate-config` and then nu-comment and edit like `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = '/home/UserName/Documents/Jupyter_Notebook'`

**NB: `/home/$USER/Documents/Jupyter_Notebook` is my changed default dir. Change it according to your need. **

Comment: I don't believe that `app_settings_dir` is needed. Why did you include it?

Comment: `c.LabApp.app_settings_dir` is needed for Jupyter Lab and for Jypyter Notebook `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir` .

Answer (score 1):

The command

`jupyter notebook --generate-config`

will create a config file.
The path to this file is displayed in your terminal or PowerShell.

Set the desired folder path as the string `c.ServerApp.root_dir` in this file and make sure you uncomment the line after you set the string.

Windows users will have to use double backslash in paths, e.g.:

`c.ServerApp.root_dir = 'C:\\YOUR\\PATH'`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71094198/16994353) . Just edit the alias alias `my_jupn='source /home/$USER/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate MyPy38 && jupyter-notebook  --notebook-dir=/home/$USER/Documents/Jupyter_Notebook'`

and for JupyterLab `alias my_jupl='source /home/$USER/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate MyPy38 && jupyter-lab --notebook-dir=/home/$USER/Documents/Jupyter_Notebook'`

**N.B.** Here *MyPy38* is your active environment name. and if any error occurs then change `$USER` to your `UserName`. Lastly, `/home/$USER/Documents/Jupyter_Notebook` will be change according to your choice.